# Add one space at the start and at the end of each string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to add one space at the start and at the end of each string in Python. I have 851 files. The first file contains 219 lines. The last line contains 1069 lines. Some line are just dots while other lines are numbers. I would like to use the center() function. I tried:

```
import os, os.path

for x in range(1, 852):
    input_file_name = f"9.{x}.txt"
    output_file_name = os.path.join(f"10.{x}.txt")
    with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
        with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            for input_line in input_file:
                output_line = input_line.center(2)
                output_file.write(output_line)
```

This just adds seventeen spaces at the beginning of each string (I want one space before each string). There is no space at the end of each string (I want one space after each string). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this:

```py
for x in range(1, 852):
    input_file_name = f"9.{x}.txt"
    output_file_name = f"10.{x}.txt"
    with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
        with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            for input_line in input_file:
                output_line = f" {input_line.rstrip("\n")} \n"
                output_file.write(output_line)
```

Comment: This returns `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` at the quotation mark after the second `\n`.

Comment: Well, I see what my error is. It's a common error. It's something you should be able to see. Can you tell us what is the error I made?